# Div com 'position: fixed' perde a largura total do contêiner

Tags: html, css

No exemplo abaixo, veja que a div naturalmente ocupa toda a largura do `body`, mas quando clico no botão <kbd>Fixar</kbd> para alterar a propriedade `position` para `fixed`, ela perde a largura total, parecendo um elemento *inline*, ocupando apenas a largura do pequeno texto dentro dela.

```js
function fixar(e){
   e.outerHTML = '';
   document.querySelector("div").style.position = "fixed";
}
```

```css
div{
   background: yellow;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   texto
</div>
<section>
   <button onClick="fixar(this)">Fixar</button>
</section>
```

Por que ao alterar a propriedade position de uma `div` para `fixed` ela deixa de ocupar toda a largura da tela, ficando apenas com a largura do conteúdo interno, como se fosse um elemento *inline*?

> Sei que usando `width: 100%` irá ocupar toda a largura, mas eu não quero
>   resolver o problema, quero entender o comportamento.

Comment: tenta colocar width:100%; no css

Comment: Obg @Zaffar, mas eu gostaria era de entender o comportamento.

Comment: Eu **acho** que isso ocorre porque ele passa a se basear no `viewport` e não mais no elemento `pai`, um outro tipo de `position` que promete ser um meio termo entre `fixed` e `relative` é o `sticky` acho que esse mantem o comportamento do `display:block`

Comment: @IcaroMartins Pois é jovem. Estranho isso. Se ele fica como referência o viewport e este é a largura da janela, ele deveria ficar na largura da janela também rs... Curioso isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## !!! Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V !!!

> *When you use `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;`, the element is taken out of the regular flow of the document.*
>
> *The default setting for `width` for a `div` element is `auto`, which means that it will use the full available width where it is. When you take it out of the flow, there is no longer any usable measure for available width (because that would be infinite), so instead the element will get its width from its content.*

Em tradução livre:

> *Quando você usa `position: fixed;` ou `position: absolute;`, o elemento é retirado do fluxo regular do documento.*
>
> *A configuração padrão para `width` de um elemento `div` é `auto`, o que significa que ele usará a largura total disponível onde está. Quando você sai do fluxo, não há mais nenhuma medida utilizável para largura disponível (porque isso seria infinito), então, em vez disso, o elemento obterá sua largura de seu conteúdo.*

---

> Fonte: [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639036/5988245) do [Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69083/guffa) no SOen.

Comment: Ambas as respostas foram bem elucidativas. Valeu!

Comment: @Sam Como assim?! A resposta do hugo tá mais completa! Acho justo aceitá-la! ;X

Answer (score 6):

Acredito que seja isso

> The size and position of an element are often impacted by its containing block. Percentage values that are applied to the width, height, padding, margin, and offset properties of an absolutely positioned element (i.e., which has its position set to absolute or fixed) are computed from the element's containing block.

"...as propriedades de deslocamento de um elemento absolutamente posicionado (isto é, que tem sua posição definida como absoluta ou fixa) são calculadas a partir do bloco contendo o elemento."

Ou seja o tamanho dele é definido pelo tamanho do próprio conteúdo. A não ser que vc declare explicitamente o tamanho dele. Então tanto para `position:absolute`, ou `position:fixed` esse comportamento ocorre de forma similar. E o tamanho do `box-model` fica como sendo o tamanho do próprio conteúdo do elemento.

Fonte na documentação oficial da Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#Effects_of_the_containing_block

---

**Um elemento fixed**

O elemento `fixed` é :

- Removido do fluxo normal do documento e nenhum espaço é criado para o elemento no layout da página.
- Ele está posicionado em relação ao primeiro `content box` que é estabelecido pelo `viewport` (existem exceções, ver link).
- A sua posição final é determinada pelos valores de `top`, `right`, `bottom`, e `left`.
- Esse valor sempre cria um novo contexto de empilhamento (`z-index`).
- Nos documentos impressos, o elemento é colocado na mesma posição em todas as páginas.

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed

Comment: #edit Estava lendo esta mesma documentação. Vou me abster da necessidade de incluir na minha resposta! xD

Comment: @LipESprY acho que uma complementa um pouco a outra. Mas o que indico sempre é tentar não usar "respostas" como respostas rss, por um simples motivo, qq resposta que seja, pode ter fatores "autorais" envolvidos... O que quero dizer nesse caso é que a resposta do cara foi baseada no que ele entendeu da documentação, foi uma interpretação dele, que as vezes a sua pode ser um pouco diferente etc, não que seja errado, mas o jeito de interpretar a documentação pode ser diferente entre as pessoas, assim como a resposta. Nesse tipo de questão sempre tento procurar a documentação base.

Comment: Acho justo! Tanto que deixei duplamente explícito que não há "nenhum texto próprio". Poderia simplesmente "linkar" nos comentários, mas achei mais útil "trazer o conteúdo do link" (como o próprio site recomenda). E mais justo ainda: referenciei a **resposta** e **o link do perfil do autor**. [In]Felizmente quando eu "obtive algo suficiente" para complementar, você já havia editado sua resposta exatamente com o conteúdo que eu iria adicionar. xD

Comment: @LipESprY http://prntscr.com/mzpa0u 

Comment: Kkkkk #off (partiu abrir uma votação pra liberar memes nos comentários)

Comment: @LipESprY Já tem um UpVote